# Configuration to load javascript resources only once

Tags: apache

I am working on application that loads about same 10 js on each page. This makes the website performance too slow. Is there a way I can changes the configuration in Apache, so that I can have all my js loaded in Cache on the home page itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, each resource - images, css, js, etc. - is loaded by Apache individually.

The way around this is to minify ([compress](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20compressor)) your JS into one file using a tool.  But, you'll have to rewrite your HTML pages to point to the new compressed file.